# disk encryption escrow files on centos via kickstart

Tags: encryption, redhat, luks

I'm trying to automate centos installs via PXE and kickstart with encrypted filesystems. In case we mislay the passphrase we want to use escrow files and encrypt them using the public key attached to an x509 certificate obtained from a web server. The relevant line in the kickstart file is

```
logvol /home --fstype ext4 --name=lv02 --vgname=vg01 --size=1 --grow --encrypted --escrowcert=http://10.0.2.2:8080/escrow.crt --passphrase=XXXX --backuppassphrase
```

Leaving the cert as PEM encoded on the web server rather than DER doesn't seem to matter, either work up to a point.

The filesystem is created and encrypted using the supplied passphrase and can be opened on reboot with no issues. Two escrow files are produced as expected and if by using the NSS database containing the private key and the first escrow file I obtain what I think is the passphrase but it doesn't unlock the disk.  For example:

```
# volume_key --secrets -d /tmp/nss e04a93fc-555b-430b-a962-1cdf921e320f-escrow
    Data encryption key:<span class="whitespace other" title="Tab">»</span>817E65AC37C1EC802E3663322BFE818D47BDD477678482E78986C25731B343C221CC1D2505EA8D76FBB50C5C5E98B28CAD440349DC0842407B46B8F116E50B34
```

I assume the string from 817 to B34 is the passphrase but using it in a cryptsetup command does not work.

```
[root@mypxetest ~]# cryptsetup -v status home
/dev/mapper/home is inactive.
Command failed with code 19.

[root@mypxetest ~]# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/rootvg01/lv02 home
Enter passphrase for /dev/rootvg01/lv02: 
No key available with this passphrase.
Enter passphrase for /dev/rootvg01/lv02:
```

When prompted I paste in the long numeric string but get the No key available message.  However if I use the passphrase specified in the kickstart file or the backup escrow file the disk unlocks.

```
# volume_key --secrets -d /tmp/nss e04a93fc-555b-430b-a962-1cdf921e320f-escrow-backup-passphrase 
Passphrase:<span class="whitespace other" title="Tab">»</span>QII.q-ImgpN-0oy0Y-RC5qa
```

Then using the string QII.q-ImgpN-0oy0Y-RC5qa in the crypsetup command works.

Has anyone any idea what I'm missing? Why don't both escrow files work?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some more reading and the file ending in escrow is not an alternative passphrase for the luks volume but it contains the encryption key which is encrypted of course.  When decrypted the long string is the encryption key and there's a clue in the rest of the text which I confess I didn't read very well.